# Rename directory inside of a tar archive

Tags: tar

Is it possible to rename a directory inside of a tar archive? My use case is that I have an externally provided RPM spec file that assumes a tarball with a certain directory structure, and I have an externally provided tarball whose top-level directory name does not match what the spec file expects. I don't control either the script that generates the tarballs or the RPM spec file, so I can't make a change to either of those to match the other.

What I have been doing is untarring, changing the directory name, and then creating a new tarball, but I was wondering if there was an alternative to doing that.

Comment: Unfortunately I doubt it, but I'd be interested to see if anyone else has a way.  I think your best bet is to write a script to untar, rename, and re-tar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It shouldn't be very difficult, at least for archives that are compatible with the old-style format where file names are stored in a fixed-size (100 bytes) field, but I don't know of any tool that can rename a file in place in a tar archive. Besides, with a compressed archive, you'd need to create a new file anyway.

It should be even easier, but I don't know of any existing tool that can filter an archive, renaming files as it goes. You can build one on top of tar libraries in scripting languages; for example, here's a proof-of-concept script to rename a directory in a tar archive using [Perl with `Archive::Tar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html). The archive is loaded entirely into memory; this is an intrinsic limitation of `Archive::Tar`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
## Usage: tar-rename OLDPREFIX NEWPREFIX
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Tar;
my ($from, $to) = @ARGV;
my $tar = Archive::Tar->new(\*STDIN);
foreach my $file ($tar->get_files()) {
    my $name = $file->name;
    $name =~ s~\A\Q$from\E($|/)~$to$1~;
    $file->rename($name) unless $name eq $file->name;
}
$tar->write(\*STDOUT);
```

GNU tar doesn't have the ability to rename members on the fly, but [`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html) (POSIX's replacement for `cpio` and `tar`) does. However, you can't make `pax` both read and write from an archive. What you can do is expose the archive as a regular tree through [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/), and create a new archive with `pax`. This retains file names (except as transformed), contents, times and modes but resets file ownership to you (unless executed as root).

```
mountavfs
cd "~/.avfs$PWD/old.tgz#"
pax -w -s '!bar!baz!' -s '!bar/!baz/' . | gzip >new.tgz
```

Comment: GNU Tar has had `--transform` since at least 2010 that does allow renaming files on the fly. For an example, see: http://scriptsandoneliners.blogspot.com/2019/11/tarf-pull-selected-files-from-tarball.html

Comment: @A.Danischewski `--transform` lets you rename files when you build or extract an archive. But how do you rename files _in an archive_ without extracting it? (Extracting is not a good solution: you may not have enough disk space; you may not have the permissions to preserve ownership information; you may not have the ability to preserve timestamps exactly...)

Comment: Okay, yea I just saw your post state that "GNU tar doesn't the ability to rename members on the fly" - it does but only on the way in/out. If you want to change names within an existing archive you can use archivemount to mount it to a directory, change whatever names you want and unmount it.

Answer (score 4):

Both sr_'s hack and Gilles' answer look very good, but if your problem is just the root directory name of the target tarball, while running rpmbuild, a different solution could be to re-define the `%setup` macro to do the needed dir renaming.

Something like (you'll have to adapt and refine this to your actual configuration, in particular replacing `old-dir` and `desired-dir` and using the right decompression tool) this in your `~/.rpmmacros`:

```
%setup cd ../BUILD \
rm -rf cd-player \
bunzip2 -dc ../SOURCES/%{name}-%{version}.tar.bz2 | tar -xvvf - \
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then \
  exit $? \
fi \
mv <old-dir> <desired-dir> \
cd <desired-dir> \
cd ../BUILD/cd-player \
chmod -R a+rX,g-w,o-w .
```

I wouldn't honestly do that if not in the most exotic situation, but yours could be the case :)

Answer (score 3):

Just view this page but found the proper answer elsewhere:

http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-macros.html

It says that you can pass -n to the %setup macro to tell rpmbuild the name of the top level folder within the tarball

Answer (score 2):

Ugly hack, but maybe this helps you, fooling `tar` with symlinks:

```
$ mkdir a b
$ date >> b/foo
$ tar zcvf b-foo.tgz b/foo
$ rm -rf b
$ ln -s a b

$ tar zxvf b-foo.tgz                                                              
x b/foo: Cannot extract through symlink b
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
$ tar zxvPf b-foo.tgz                                                             
x b/foo
$ ls a
foo
```

Thinking about it, it probably doesn't, as `rpm` won't let you mess with the arguments to `tar`, would it?  (Edit: maybe some tricky `tar` wrapper script in `$PATH` could get you around this.)

Answer (score 0):

This article was so close to what I needed but no cigar. The rename function inside of Archive::Tar was messing up my folders. It worked great for files but the folders were coming out without the trailing slash (/). Example:

Before

```
$VAR1 = [
          'old_root_folder/',
          'old_root_folder/.dockerignore',
          'old_root_folder/.github/',
.....
```

After

```
$VAR1 = [
          'newrootfolder',
          'newrootfolder/.dockerignore',
          'newrootfolder/.github/',
......
```

Notice the root folder no longer has the slash designation! Turns out that doesn't matter. The new archive extracts fine without the folders ending with a trailing slash

I ended up with the following Perl snippet:

```
sub renameRootFolderInTar
{
    my $file = shift;
    my $new_root_folder_name = shift;
    my $tar = Archive::Tar->new($file);
    my @files_in_archive = $tar->list_files;
    my $root_folder = @files_in_archive[0]; # whatever they named the root folder in the archive
    $root_folder =~ s/\/$//g;
    foreach(@files_in_archive)
    {
        my $this_archive_file = $_;
        my $dest = $this_archive_file;
        $dest =~ s/^$root_folder\/(.*)/$new_root_folder_name\/$1/g;
        $tar->rename($this_archive_file,$dest);
    }
    my $success = $tar->write( "renamed.tar.gz", COMPRESS_GZIP );
    if($success)
    {
        unlink $file;
        return "renamed.tar.gz";
    }
    else
    {
        print "Sorry, there was a problem when dealing with the raw archive $file:\n";
        print "Could not save renamed.tar.gz\n";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Admittedly this assumes that the first entry in the archive is a folder. But you get the idea.